# Django boolean field for listing

Tags: python, django, templates

I have listing field in all my classes to allow admins check or uncheck if they'd like item to be listed as below:

```
listing = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My challenge is in template. Im using a if and else statement to achieve this by

```
{% if listing %}
show them all
{% endif %}
```

and this is my view

```
def AllMovies (request):
movies= Movie.objects.all().order_by('movie_name')
context = {'movies': movies}
return render_to_response('allmovies.html', context, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

But django doesnt show anything despite listing is checked in my admin panel

Im sure im doing something wrong here as this is my first time working with templates. Could you guys please help me to understand what is the best approach here?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add your view?

Comment: Hi Brandon, ive added it

Comment: you dont pass listing to your template do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass listing to the template, else it doesn't know what it is. I'm guessing you want something like this:

view:

```
context = {'user': request.user}
```

template:

```
{% if user.listing %}
   show them all...
{% endif %}
```

p.s.

I kinda guessed that listing is something you assigned to the users, though your description was a bit confusing, so y'know... if I'm wrong just apply it for the right object. if it's a field that each movies has then it would probably be something like this:

```
{% for movie in movies %}
   {% if movie.listing %}
       {{ movie }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am passing it, it is part of my model, also I dont have anything to do with user. doesnt this pass my fields to template?  movies= Movie.objects.all().order_by('movie_name')

Comment: @user3482036 part of what model?